# How can I run a forEach through my array of objects and set a value for the object property that has an empty string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, foreach

**Part 1 question:** How can I use forEach to loop through my array of objects to set the object property of profile_image_url which has an empty string to a default link/value("/media/artist/img_0930-1-9654.jpg").Set the value for only empty strings. I am exploring forEach loop right now. Below is my sample json. I have a json of 20000 users.

**Part 2 question:** Which one am I better off? Iterate through forEach or regular for loop?

**JSON**

```
[{
    "country": "",
    "artist_id": 4,
    "email": "LzoCqLeVpy8h@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": ""
}, {
    "country": "",
    "artist_id": 5,
    "email": "P6H77fnNvgdn@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": ""
}, {
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 6,
    "email": "Cjdd4gzSfKM4@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/zizmor_039_low_res-1239.jpg"
}, {
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 7,
    "email": "m8G3gdhOQmB6@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/img_0930-1-7654.jpg"
}]
```

Comment: What value is to set for empty values?

Comment: @ Tushar: "/media/artist/img_0930-1-9654.jpg"

Comment: For all users with `''` string?

Comment: Just the ones with empty strings.

Comment: Do you need to loop at all - that's 2000 iterations. If the use is only going to see 1 or 2, then you could just test for that when you display the info to them

Comment: Generally: *foreach = Iterate through objects, for = Iterate through arrays*. In your case you would just want to use a normal `for` since it's an array. Although you can use `foreach` to go through properties in the objects.

Comment: It will display 50 users at any given time.

Comment: It is fine if this is a one time exercise, can become very costly if you are doing it again and again. Depending on the case, you may want to use the default value on the UI front or if the data is something you save on your DB, adding a check to a before-save hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Part 1 question**: How can I use forEach to loop through my array of objects to set the object property of `profile_image_url` which has an empty string to a default link/value("/media/artist/img_0930-1-9654.jpg").

[**forEach** documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var arr = [{
  "country": "",
  "artist_id": 4,
  "email": "LzoCqLeVpy8h@example.com",
  "profile_image_url": ""
}, {
  "country": "",
  "artist_id": 5,
  "email": "P6H77fnNvgdn@example.com",
  "profile_image_url": ""
}, {
  "country": "US",
  "artist_id": 6,
  "email": "Cjdd4gzSfKM4@example.com",
  "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/zizmor_039_low_res-1239.jpg"
}, {
  "country": "US",
  "artist_id": 7,
  "email": "m8G3gdhOQmB6@example.com",
  "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/img_0930-1-7654.jpg"
}];

// e: element, i: index
arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if (e.profile_image_url === '') {
    arr[i].profile_image_url = '/media/artist/img_0930-1-9654.jpg';
  }
});

console.log(arr);
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

> **Part 2 question:** Which one am I better off? Iterate through `forEach` or regular for `loop`?

Using `forEach` has benefits of getting `index` and `value` from the array. You don't have to explicitly set the index `var i = 0;`, get the value from array `arr[i]` and use `arr.length` for iteration.

Check http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html

Comment: A to Y via dirt roads.

Comment: JSON.stringify/parse has to "iterate over 1000s of objects"; in fact, this approach has to *re-create* "1000s of" new objects, which a simple iteration would not require.

Comment: Furthermore, since the exact text of the JSON (ignoring the possibility this approach is extended to the text result of a web API) is *not guaranteed* (eg. it could have inserted any number, or zero, valid JSON white-space characters) a valid/conforming ECMAScript engine could fail with the regex code.

Comment: @user2864740 You're right, I run jsperf test http://jsperf.com/foreach-vs-json, using `JSON....` is slower for four objects, might be faster for 1000 objects, updated answer

Answer (score 2):

**Part 1:**

```js
var users = [{
    "country": "",
    "artist_id": 4,
    "email": "LzoCqLeVpy8h@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": ""
}, {
    "country": "",
    "artist_id": 5,
    "email": "P6H77fnNvgdn@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": ""
}, {
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 6,
    "email": "Cjdd4gzSfKM4@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/zizmor_039_low_res-1239.jpg"
}, {
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 7,
    "email": "m8G3gdhOQmB6@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/img_0930-1-7654.jpg"
}];

users.forEach(function(user) {
  if (!user.profile_image_url) {
    user.profile_image_url = "/media/artist/img_0930-1-9654.jpg";
  }
});

document.getElementById('users').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(users, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="users"></pre>
```

**Part 2**

There won't be much difference if any between using an imperative for loop vs forEach.

The alternative you can consider is defaulting to that image url when you encounter an empty string as a `profile_image_url`.

---

Using angular as an example, when binding to a view if the `profile_img_url` is an empty string use the default url.

```js
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.users = [{
    "country": "",
    "artist_id": 4,
    "email": "LzoCqLeVpy8h@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": ""
  }, {
    "country": "",
    "artist_id": 5,
    "email": "P6H77fnNvgdn@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": ""
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 6,
    "email": "Cjdd4gzSfKM4@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/zizmor_039_low_res-1239.jpg"
  }, {
    "country": "US",
    "artist_id": 7,
    "email": "m8G3gdhOQmB6@example.com",
    "profile_image_url": "/media/artist/img_0930-1-7654.jpg"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div>Email: {{user.email}}</div>
    <div>Profile Image: {{user.profile_image_url || "/media/artist/img_0930-1-9654.jpg"}}</div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would pursue the idea of using a default at the usage site.